# Grails DuplicateKeyException / NonUniqueObjectException when batch loading within Async Promise

Tags: grails, asynchronous, grails-orm, promise, batch-processing

I have a large amount of data that I wish to load into a DB using GORM.

```
class DbLoadingService {

    static transactional = false    
    // these are used to expedite the batch loading process
    def sessionFactory
    def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

    // these are example services that will assist in the parsing of the input data    
    def auxLoadingServiceA
    def auxLoadingServiceB

    def handleInputFile(String filename) {
        def inputFile = new File(filename)
        // parse each line and process according to record type
        inputFile.eachLine { line, lineNumber ->
            this.handleLine(line, lineNumber)
        }
    }


    @Transactional
    def handleLine(String line, int lineNumber) {
        // do some further parsing of the line, based on its content
        // example here is based on 1st 2 chars of line
        switch (line[0..1]) {
            case 'AA':
                auxLoadingServiceA.doSomethingWithLine(line)
                break;

            case 'BB':
                auxLoadingServiceB.doSomethingElseWithLine(line)
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
        if (lineNumber % 100 == 0) cleanUpGorm()
    }

    def cleanUpGorm() {
        def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
        propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
    }

}

class AuxLoadingServiceA {
    static transactional = false

    doSomethingWithLine(String line) {
        // do something here
    }
}

class AuxLoadingServiceB {
    static transactional = false

    doSomethingElseWithLine(String line) {
        // do something else here
    }
}
```

I have deliberately made the top-level service transactional only for the load of each line.  There are actually quite a number of levels of services under the top-level, not just the single Aux A & B service-layer shown.  I therefore don't want to have the overhead of multiple layered transactions: I think I should only require 1.

The data model being loaded into the DB includes a couple of domain objects that have hasMany / belongsTo relationships.  This interaction with the domain objects is done within the sub-layers and is not shown in my code in order to keep the example manageable in size.

The domain object that seems to be causing the problem looks similar to this:

```
class Parent {
    static hasMany = [children: Child]
    static mapping = {
        children lazy: false
        cache true
    }
}

class Child {
    String someValue
    // also contains some other sub-objects

    static belongsTo = [parent : Parent]

    static mapping = {
        parent index: 'parent_idx'
        cache true
    }
}
```

The cleanupGorm() method shown is required, otherwise the service grinds to a complete halt after a large number of lines.

When I initiate the database load, all works absolutely as expected:

```
// Called from with a service / controller
dbLoadingService.handleInputFile("someFile.txt")
```

However, as soon as I move the load into an asynchronous process, like this:

```
def promise = task {
    dbLoadingService.handleInputFile("someFile.txt")
}
```

I get a DuplicateKeyException / NonUniqueObjectException:

```
error details: org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.SampleDomainObject#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.SampleDomainObject#1]
```

So, my question is, what are the best practices around asynchronous loading of large quantities of data into a Grails DB?  Is there something that needs to be done with regards flushing / clearing the session in order to ensure that objects in memory are consistent in the session?  Is there something that needs to be done when caching objects?

Comment: First, you should never do heavy batch processing like this. Use a real batch processing framework like Spring Batch. However, have you tried using new hibernate sessions for each task? That may help.

Comment: New hibernate sessions, meaning a new hibernate session within here?  inputFile.eachLine { line, lineNumber ->
            this.handleLine(line, lineNumber)
        }

Comment: Yep, using this: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html

Comment: That's just a wild guess though. It really sounds like hibernate is getting confused about the state of things.

Comment: Thanks very much, will take a look - the logic to parse the file involves multiple domain classes within the auxiliary methods, so I'm not sure it fits easily into the Spring Batch model or withNewSession, which seems to work only on a single domain class?

Comment: With new session just starts a new session. The class used is just there to get a pointer to it, it spans all domain classes inside the session. Spring batch works great with very complex models as well.

Comment: Ah, great, wish the docs mentioned that! Will take a look tomorrow, thanks for the tip, John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do as suggested by @JoshuaMoore and to use new sessions.  Additionally, there was a reference to a domain object that was being referred to from outside one transaction that was then not having merge() called on it within a new session, thereby causing the error.

i.e.

```
def obj = DomainObject.findBySomeProperty('xyz')

// now start new session

obj.someProperty // causes exception
obj = obj.merge()
obj.someProperty // doesn't cause an exception
```

Joshua's comment prompted me to dig into the documentation for Hibernate (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html)

Specifically, from Chapter 13:

> A SessionFactory is an expensive-to-create, threadsafe object,
>   intended to be shared by all application threads. It is created once,
>   usually on application startup, from a Configuration instance.
>
> A Session is an inexpensive, non-threadsafe object that should be used
>   once and then discarded for: a single request, a conversation or a
>   single unit of work. A Session will not obtain a JDBC Connection, or a
>   Datasource, unless it is needed. It will not consume any resources
>   until used.

What may be of interest to others was that I had been seeing a gradual degradation in performance of the batch load with increasing numbers of objects being parsed, even with the performance optimisation suggested by Burt Beckwith [here](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=73):  and explained in further detail by Ted Naleid [here](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql).

So, using the hint from the documentation, the answer to the performance issue is not to try to use the session for all the processing - instead use it to do a small amount of processing, then throw it away and create a new one.

When I removed the cleanupGorm() method in my question and replaced it with the following, I got a **6-times increase in performance**, with absolutely no increase in load time with batch size, even after 10s of millions of records being parsed:

```
// somewhere in the service method that is doing the batch parse
def currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession()

// start some form of batch parse, perhaps in a loop

    // do work here
    // periodically, perhaps in the %N way shown above
    currentSession.flush()
    currentSession.close()
    currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession()

// end of loop
```

Where I was needing to wrap up stuff in a transaction that spanned services, I did the following:

```
currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession()
currentSession.beginTransaction()

// start loop
// do work

// when we want to commit
def tx = currentSession?.getTransaction()
if (tx?.isActive()) tx.commit()
currentSession?.close()

// if we're in a loop and we need a new transaction
currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession()
currentSession.beginTransaction()
```

Whilst I accept that using something like Spring Batch is probably better, it would have involved throwing away large volumes of code that otherwise works as expected.  I will look into that next time I need to do this, but in the meantime, hopefully this may be of use to someone else needing to do large-scale batch processing with Grails and is finding that there is a degradation in performance with batch size.

Note to Joshua: thank you very much for the help, very much appreciated!